# Span elements still visible after display:none;

Tags: html, css, visibility, font-awesome, display

I have four span elements that serve as Font Awesome (icon font service) stacks meaning that they each contain two font-awesome "i" elements.

```
       <span class="fa-stack fa-2x left-arrow-button portfolio-arrow-button">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x fa-lg button-circle-background" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-stack-2x left-arrow-img" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x right-arrow-button portfolio-arrow-button">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x fa-lg button-circle-background" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-stack-2x right-arrow-img" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x left-arrow-button-2 portfolio-arrow-button">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x fa-lg button-circle-background" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-stack-2x left-arrow-img" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x right-arrow-button-2 portfolio-arrow-button">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x fa-lg button-circle-background" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-stack-2x right-arrow-img" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
```

I created a CSS media query at a min-width of 1290px, and wanted to hide these span elements (and their children of course) starting at this query size.

So, I added (at this query size) the class "portfolio-arrow-button" to all of these span elements and gave them a declaration of display: none;

This didn't work.

Knowing that when it comes to making style overrides to Font Awesome icons it sometimes requires using the :before pseudo selector, I tried:

".portfolio-arrow-button:before", but to no avail.

What eventually worked to hide the buttons was: targeting each "i" element, within their parent span element, and using the :before pseudo selector, then using the "display: none;" declaration.

```
.button-circle-background:before, .left-arrow-img:before, .right-arrow-img:before {
        display: none;
       }
```

Although I'm glad that this hid the "buttons" themselves, **I would really like for the span elements to be gone from the page entirely also.**

No they are not visible, but when inspected with the debugger, they are still there (the span containers, not their children).

[image: bug-screenshot]

Anyone have any ideas on how to get rid of them or why this is the case?

**Help is greatly appreciated, thank you!**

Comment: because, last css for span is display:inline-block; write display:none; after that

Comment: The "display: none;" declaration is the last declaration in my CSS styles file, but for some reason, Font Awesome icons tend to override any personal styles. 

The "display: inline;" declaration is one added automatically by Font Awesome and not in my style sheet. 

That's why I mentioned that I tried using the ":before" pseudo selector when targeting the element in my CSS (since that usually works to override Font Awesome automatic styles) but it didn't work.

Comment: main.css is before font-awesome.css?

Comment: Your dev tools screenshot suggests that you are embedding the fontawesome CSS file _after_ your main.css, and that's why your rule with the same specificity (if that doesn't mean anything to you, look it up) gets overwritten by the latter one. Either change the order in which those stylesheet are embedded, or use a selector with higher specificity.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! Didn't notice that!

Comment: Made the change, but Font-Awesome styles still override my CSS styles.

Comment: Well, the specificity did the trick, thanks! 

I had previously thought that selecting an element by class name was very specific, but I guess not. 

krzychek's example of "#Portfolio > span {} worked great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

krzychek is correct in the answer above (main.css is overwritten by font-awesome-css.min.css) but if you cannot change the order of the files, then here's another way to do it:

### CSS

```
#Portfolio > span {display:none;}
```

Comment: I realize this is really old, but can you, or someone else elaborate on exactly why this works?

This gets overridden by FontAwesome

`#closeNav { display: none; }`

While this doesn't:

`#mainNav > #closeNav { display: none; }`

Answer (score 3):

as I can see in dev tools, both styles are being applied to element, but one from `font-awesome-css.min.css` is chosen.
Is `main.css` placed after `font-awesome-css.min.css`?

I'm not CSS guru, but my guess is that `main.css` is placed before other css and therefore overridden by following rules :P

Also you can add `!important` directive after `display:none`. However it is smelly and better to avoid.

Answer (score -2):

Add this code inside the head of your web page:

```
<style>
   span.fa-stack { display:none !important; }
</style>
```